# C# 11 static method inhertance

Tags: c#, .net, c#-11.0

I am checking out the new static inhertance that comes with c# 11. I was trying to invoke a static member via reflection i would assume the inherited property would be executed but that doesn't seem the case and i get a MethodNotFoundException.

My code

```cs
public abstract class MyBaseClass {
  public static string MyProp { get => "default";} 
}

public class Subclass1 : MyBaseClass {
  public static new string MyProp { get => "myprop";}
}

public class Subclass2 : MyBaseClass {

}
```

```cs
public static class Program {  
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {      
        // outputs "default"
        var test1 = MyBaseClass.MyProp;

        // outputs "myprop"
        var test2 = Subclass1.MyProp;

        // outputs "default"
        var test3 = Subclass2.MyProp;

        // outputs "default"
        var test4 = typeof(MyBaseClass).InvokeMember("MyProp", BindingFlags.GetProperty,null,null,null);

        // outputs "myprop"
        var test5 = typeof(Subclass1).InvokeMember("MyProp", BindingFlags.GetProperty,null,null,null);

        //throws exception
        var test6 = typeof(Subclass2).InvokeMember("MyProp", BindingFlags.GetProperty,null,null,null);
    }     
}
```

As you can see `test6` throws an error but `test3` succeeds. Is there anyway i can retrieve the value that  `test3` outputs via the `Type` (with reflection)?

Comment: Remove Static from the property.

Comment: Yes i can just make instances and there is probably a 100 ways to do this, but i am asking why this doesn't work

Comment: What is the problem with accessing it via `typeof(MyBaseClass)`?

Comment: Wouldn't that always return `default`? even if the class is changed to have the static property?

Comment: I always assumed you could do the same with reflection that you could in normal code. And this principle has basically never failed me until now. I can make a check to see if the class implements the static prop and if false then do the same for the base class of the subclass but that seems a bit tedious.

Comment: I also saw that the `BindingFlags` have a `Static` value but i don't know what it exactly does so i tought maybe it's possible with that and someone else knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# 11, static members are not inherited by derived classes. Each derived class can define its own static member with the same name as the base class, effectively hiding the base class's static member. This behavior is known as "shadowing."

In your example, `Subclass2` does not define its own `MyProp` static member, so it inherits the `MyProp` member from `MyBaseClass`. That's why `test3` correctly outputs "default."

However, when using reflection to access static members, the member lookup is not affected by shadowing. When you invoke `typeof(Subclass2).InvokeMember("MyProp", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null)`, it searches for a static member named `MyProp` directly on `Subclass2`. Since `Subclass2` does not define its own `MyProp`, the member is not found, and a `MethodNotFoundException` is thrown.

To retrieve the inherited static member via reflection, you can modify your code as follows:

```cs
var baseProp = typeof(MyBaseClass).GetProperty("MyProp", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var test6 = baseProp.GetValue(null);
```

In this code, we explicitly retrieve the `MyProp` property from the `MyBaseClass` using reflection and then get its value by passing `null` as the instance parameter to `GetValue`. This will correctly retrieve the value of the inherited static member.

Keep in mind that reflection can have performance implications, and it's generally recommended to use direct access to static members whenever possible.

Comment: It still threw an exception i adjusted the code a little bit and now it works: `var baseProp = typeof(Subclass2).GetProperty("MyProp", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);`
`var test6 = baseProp.GetValue(null);`. Seems i needed the FlattenHierachy option.